# Can not finish to create new polygon by right click in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon

I am using QGIS 3.8.1 on Mac and trying to create new Polygon in this step. However it does not work.

- Menu,  Layer, Create Layer, New Create Temporary Scratch Layer
- click toggle editing icon
- click Add polygon feature
- create Polygon at map
  [image]
- right click and then Polygon disappear, there is no attribute windows pop up
  [image]

Comment: Sounds like a bug. You can reinstall QGIS and run it without plugins to see if it continues to happen

Comment: Hi Thanks for your comment. I uninstall 3.8.1 and install 3.4.1 which is LTR (long time release). It works.

Answer (score 6):

the polygon layer is below `OpenStreetMap`. A new polygon being edited is always on top of everything. As soon as you finish the drawing, the polygon is "moved" to its layer, and since OSM is above it you just can't see it. Move the layer above OSM and you will see all the polygons

Answer (score 2):

In my case, at least, I worked out that it depends on whether my cursor (ready for the next click to create the next point in the line or polygon) is hovering over any map feature in any level that it could snap to. If so, a hover text should appear by your cursor showing the name of that feature. Right-clicking doesn’t work when this is the case. But just move your cursor away to any blank space on the map where there is no feature that it wants to snap to, and then right-click, and it should work. (The usual dialogue box should pop up for you to enter the ID for your newly completed line or polygon.)